# Existence of an irreducible polynomial that does not divide $x^n + a$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, fields

**The question:**

Can one characterize all fields $K$ over which there exists an *irreducible* polynomial $f(x)$ that *does not* divide a polynomial of the form $x^n + a$?

**Examples:**

- Such a polynomial clearly exists over $\mathbb{Q}$.
- It also exists over $\mathbb{R}$ (the polynomial with roots $(3 + 4i)/5$ and $(3 - 4i)/5$).
- As far as I understand, such polynomials do not exist over finite fields.
- Apart from the trivial case of $K$ algebraically closed, this is the only negative example I know. I would thus also appreciate any example of an infinite field over which there is no polynomial with the described properties.

**Possibly related:**

I have found some papers dealing with possible multiplicative relations between roots of polynomials over certain fields (for example, [this one](https://eudml.org/doc/207093)). However, these do not seem to directly address my question. I suspect that my question should be much easier (hopefully not completely trivial).

Comment: Separably closed fields are also examples: if $L/K$ is purely inseparable, then for any $a\in L$, you have $a^{p^n}\in K$ for some $n$.

Comment: I think the Galois group of a splitting field for $x^n+a$ is abelian (right?) so I would guess that a sufficient condition is that the absolute Galois group of $K$ be non-abelian.

Comment: @PaulLevy No, that's not the case - $x^4-2$ has nonabelian Galois group. It is, however, solvable, so unsolvability of the absolute Galois group is a sufficient condition.

Comment: @Wojowu Ok, the absolute Galois group of the field obtained from $K$ by adjoining all roots of unity should be non-abelian...